# Java URLConnection - When do I need to use the connect() method?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have a problem to understand the meaning of the `connect()` method in the `URLConnection` class. In the following code, if I use the `connect()` method, I get the same result if I don't use it.

Why (or when) do I need to use it?

```
URL u = new URL("http://example.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

conn.connect();//with or without it I have the same result

InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
int b;
while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
 System.out.write(b);
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
```

only creates an Object

`connect()` method is invoked by `conn.getInputStream();`

Answer (score 35):

You are not always required to explicitly call the connect method to initiate the connection.

Operations that depend on being connected, like `getInputStream`, `getOutputStream`, etc, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

Here's the oracle doc [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html)