# How to download file from server using http in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to download file from URL using `HttpURLConnection` in Android.

First I added textviews programmatically and set a listener to each textviews to download a file.
Below is that code.

```
for(Element ele: elements){
            final TextView attachItem = new TextView(this);
            attachItem.setText("myStr");
            attachItem.setTag("myStr2");

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            attachItem.setLayoutParams(llp);

            ll.addView(attachItem, i++);

            // set a listener to textview
            attachItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // when clicked, execute class that extends `AsyncTask`
                    new downloadAttach().
                            execute(attachItem.getTag().toString(), attachItem.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        }
```

And `downloadAttach()` downloads a file from server using http protocol. Below is code.

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("MyUrl")).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        ...
        ...
        ...
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "myCookie");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        output.writeBytes("myQuery");
        output.close();

        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), "fileName"));
        // In my case, getDataDirectory() returns "/data"

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        is.close();
        fos.close();
```

But when I click a textview, nothing changes. There isn't a file in `/data` directory in my phone.

What's the problem? Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to download file in sd-card? if yes try changing path to

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename
```

or 
in you app package directory  use `"/data/packagename/" + filename`.

Comment: I think you should first add log to check if the parameters transfered to downloadTask is correct and then if the downloading happened normally.

Comment: @ChineGary I think parameters are transfered correctly. How can I check if the downloading happened normally? There are no exceptions at all...

Comment: I think  fos.flush() should be called before fos.close().Then you could also add some logs to record how many bytes was wrote to fos,if it's the same as the file size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`#connect`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()), otherwise the request is never made.

```
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);

con.connect();

DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: I've always used the `#connect` method, but it seems that calling`#getOutputStream` or `#getInputStream` [implicitly invokes it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18742082/1047268).