# What is wrong with this GET request?

Tags: java, android

So we are working on this app in Android Studio where we want to make a get request to a website, and when we run this piece of code, we keep getting an error of "null" which I believe to be so because one of the variables in this piece of code is null. Can someone look it over and see any places where you may detect some variable is not being used correctly and therefore providing a null error?

```
public class SpotAlgo {
String vidLink;
int linkLoc;
String testString = "<title>";
String result;

public String gettheResult(String v) throws Exception{
    String sname = " ";
    vidLink = "https://open.spotify.com/track/43PuMrRfbyyuz4QpZ3oAwN";

    URL obj = new URL(vidLink);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine = "";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    result = response.toString();


    linkLoc = result.indexOf(testString) + testString.length();
    for (int i = linkLoc; i < result.indexOf("on Spotify"); i++) {
        sname += result.charAt(i) + "";
    }
    return obj.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Provice a stacktrace please.

Comment: So, what happens if the returned text doesn't contain `"on Spotify"`, such as if the URL returns a 404 error? Please, as mentioned above, supply your LogCat so we can see what the error is.

Comment: The stacktrace is: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa8d63f60, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH

Comment: @enzokie are u referring to the website itself that ive provided? When I run it through postman I am getting a proper response

Comment: @Enzokie HEAD request returns 200 for me... Anyways, Programmer87, Volley / OkHttp may be better HTTP libraries for your needs.

Comment: Yeah it is a 200 request for me now, probably I did use a wrong request.

Comment: @enzokie so do you see any other sources of problem?

Comment: @cricket_007 point taken. But I would rather use this connection toolset now because I feel more familiar with it

Comment: Do you have the proper permission in your manifest?

Comment: @enzokie what do you mean by that? Sorry I am a bit new to android programming

Comment: @Programmer87 [Mainfest permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application#2169311). You also need an AsyncTask to even run this code off the UI Thread.

Comment: And you are parsing HTML? So, look into JSoup. `indexOf("<title>")` does not seem reliable.

Comment: @cricket_007 Realized that internet permission wasnt there and I added that... Nothing is being returned now instead of just a null statement

Comment: Okay... where is null returned? It is `"null"` (a string), `null` (no object), or NullPointerException, an issue with your exception catching? As Nobody pointed out below, the code seems to work with what you provided, so unless you provide the stacktrace and a [mcve], we cannot help anymore

Comment: @cricket_007 I think it may actually be an issue with the emulator itself. How would I enable the emulator to have internet access on Windows?

Comment: Should have access by default. I use Genymotion, though, so not sure

Answer (score 0):

Nothing, it works fine!

I believe that if you have a null pointer exception, it is related to another part of your code.

However, here are some suggestions to improve it

In this snippet you add text to the sname variable in a loop. When you do that kind of operation a StringBuilder will be more efficient.

```
for (int i = linkLoc; i < result.indexOf("on Spotify"); i++) {
   sname += result.charAt(i) + "";
}
//Could be replaced b
for (int i = linkLoc; i < result.indexOf("on Spotify"); i++) {
    sb.append(result.charAt(i));
}
```

You can later use sb.toString() to get the result of the operation.

Also, more importantly, when you do network operation you never know what the result will be. There can be many variables that will inpact the result you will get, and often exceptions will be thrown. It is important that you wrap the network code in a try { } finally {}, and that you close the ressources you open in the finally block (a finally block always execute).

**edit**
Fixed a typo

**edit 2**

Some people are saying it is throwing a 404 exception, I did not get one when I ran it on my machine, and a 404 would throw an IOException when you do con.getInputStream(), so you would likely see that instead

Comment: It was my mistake, its returning 200 now.

Comment: @Nobody so are you saying that me assembling the string is what is giving the null error?

Comment: No, there is no null error in the code you provided. I am just pointing out a more efficient way of assembling it.

Comment: @enzokie what are you getting for the value of sname then when you run it?

Comment: @Programmer87 I am getting the HTML page text.

Comment: I'm getting "Exchange, a song by Bryson Tiller " when I run your code, directly copy-pasted

Comment: @Nobody really you are getting that? thats so weird. Thats the value we are trying to get, but it keeps coming up as null

Comment: @Nobody one thing that should be noted actually, is that when this code is ran in eclipse, it actually works. But when we move it onto android studio, the null error comes up

Comment: When you say null error,  you mean a crash or it returns null?  Because you return obj.toString and not sname,  so it might be from that

Comment: yea that was just for testing purposes. I changed it to sname and its still returning null

Comment: Can you post the console message?

Comment: @Nobody Are you running my code in android studio or eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

You missed actually connecting

```
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.connect();
```

Your con.getInputStream(); is null since the connection is not made and nothing is returned to con.

Comment: There is no need for you to explicitly call `con.connect()` because it is implicitly invoked the moment you use `getInputStream` or `getOutputStream()`. For more info see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122999/java-urlconnection-when-do-i-need-to-use-the-connect-method).

Comment: Alright we added con.connect(), but it is still giving a null. It is not displaying where it is coming from either

Comment: what sort of header would I add?

Comment: @Programmer87 Are you sure that it returns response?. Try putting Log.w("Error Check------", in );    Just before while loop and see the debug if it print out anything